# Apache ignite query from set

Tags: caching, ignite

is it possible to query values from set? for example,

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
  /** Person ID (indexed). */
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private long id;

  /** Department ID (indexed). */
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private Set deptIds;

  /** First name (not-indexed). */
  @QuerySqlField
  private String firstName;

  /** Last name (not indexed). */
  @QuerySqlField
  private String lastName;

}
```

now i want to get all employee for one particular department.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with Scan queries, but not possible with SQL queries.

Looks like you use SQL queries. In this case you have to think in terms of relational databases. There is a many-to-many relationship between Employee and Department, so you have to add a *Junction Table*.

```
public class EmployeeDepartment implements Serializable {
  /** Person ID (indexed). */
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private long personId;

  /** Department ID (indexed). */
  @QuerySqlField(index = true)
  private long deptId;
}
```

After that you can do a three way join to find employees for a particular department.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am looking for alternative from Aerospike which has List & Set support along with Index so i can fire in query. but seems Ignite does not support List/Set as part of main object which can be indexed.